# Material UI GridList drop down is too wide

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a menu / drop down in Material UI that is in the shape of a grid. The drop downs I've seen in the documentation are either a single column or a single row. I've taken a stab at this using a menu component that contains a `GridList` and this almost works for me but the grid is too wide and there is too much space between the columns. I've tried using `GridListItem` and `Grid` container and `GridItem` but I've ended up with the same issue.

```
   <Menu
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        elevation={0}
        getContentAnchorEl={null}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "left" }}
        transformOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "left" }}
        TransitionComponent={Fade}
      >
        <GridList cellHeight={48} cols={2}>
          <Button onClick={(e) => handleClose(LayoutIcons.L_1x1)}>
            {GetGroupIcon(LayoutIcons.L_1x1)}
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={(e) => handleClose(LayoutIcons.L_2x2)}>
            {GetGroupIcon(LayoutIcons.L_2x2)}
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={(e) => handleClose(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}>
            {GetGroupIcon(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={(e) => handleClose(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}>
            {GetGroupIcon(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={(e) => handleClose(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}>
            {GetGroupIcon(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={(e) => handleClose(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}>
            {GetGroupIcon(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}
          </Button>
        </GridList>
      </Menu>
```

[CodeSandbox for sample grid drop down](https://codesandbox.io/s/square-menu-grid-example-qb65k?file=/demo.tsx:5284-6500)

After digging into this I found that the width of the grid is the sum of all the element widths because it's using flex as the display (in my example code it is 6 but my solution requires a general grid of any number of elements and columns). The grid then sets the width of each element based on the number of columns. I have 2 columns so each element width is set to 50%. This provides 2 elements per row but makes each element very wide.

I am looking for a Material UI solution to tighten the element width so each item is as far apart as when I set the number of columns to 6 in my example code. I'm fine with adjustments using `GridList` or `Grid` or a completely different approach as long as it is using Material UI components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use block elements such as `div`. Close each row in another block element. Add margins if you need more spacing

```
<div>
  <div>
    <Button onClick={(e) => handleClose(LayoutIcons.L_1x1)}>
      {GetGroupIcon(LayoutIcons.L_1x1)}
    </Button>
    <Button onClick={(e) => handleClose(LayoutIcons.L_2x2)}>
      {GetGroupIcon(LayoutIcons.L_2x2)}
    </Button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <Button onClick={(e) => handleClose(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}>
      {GetGroupIcon(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}
    </Button>
    <Button onClick={(e) => handleClose(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}>
      {GetGroupIcon(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}
    </Button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <Button onClick={(e) => handleClose(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}>
      {GetGroupIcon(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}
    </Button>
    <Button onClick={(e) => handleClose(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}>
      {GetGroupIcon(LayoutIcons.L_5x5)}
    </Button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Edit Square Menu Grid Example (forked)]